# Oracle query using 'with' keyword fails in ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, query, oracle-spatial

I am trying to return a spatial resultant by throwing a fairly long and complex query at some datasets in an Oracle database, and returning a resultant via ogr2ogr. The goal is to return a resultant in a GeoJSON format after doing a right excluding join - this saves me the need to later run a Python cursor to weed out records with an ID number found in two different datasets.

Here is the Oracle query, tested successfully against an Oracle 12c database (Warning: it's long):

```
with table1 as (
     select forcov.OPENING_ID as forcov_OP
    from WHSE_FOREST_VEGETATION.RSLT_FOREST_COVER_POLY forcov,
       WHSE_LAND_USE_PLANNING.RMP_LANDSCAPE_UNIT_SVW lu
  where lu.LANDSCAPE_UNIT_NAME = 'Ladybird'
  and UPPER(forcov.SILV_POLYGON_NO) NOT LIKE 'PAS%'and
      UPPER(forcov.SILV_POLYGON_NO)  NOT LIKE '%WTR%' and
     UPPER(forcov.SILV_POLYGON_NO)  NOT LIKE '%WTP%' and
    UPPER(forcov.SILV_POLYGON_NO)  NOT LIKE '%RD%' and
   UPPER(forcov.SILV_POLYGON_NO) NOT LIKE 'RES%' and
  UPPER(forcov.SILV_POLYGON_NO)  NOT LIKE '%ROAD%' and
  UPPER(forcov.SILV_POLYGON_NO)  NOT LIKE '%LANDING%'
  and ((SDO_RELATE(forcov.GEOMETRY,  lu.GEOMETRY, 'mask=inside') = 'TRUE')
  or (SDO_RELATE(forcov.GEOMETRY,  lu.GEOMETRY, 'mask=OVERLAPBDYINTERSECT') = 'TRUE')))  ,

table2 as (
      select vri.OPENING_ID as vri_op, vri.GEOMETRY as GEOM_vri,
      case when LINE_7B_DISTURBANCE_HISTORY like ('L%') and TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(LINE_7B_DISTURBANCE_HISTORY, 2,2)) <= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YY')
        then ('2000' + SUBSTR(vri.LINE_7B_DISTURBANCE_HISTORY, 2,2))
      when LINE_7B_DISTURBANCE_HISTORY like ('L%') and TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(LINE_7B_DISTURBANCE_HISTORY, 2,2)) > TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YY')  
        then('1900' + SUBSTR(vri.LINE_7B_DISTURBANCE_HISTORY, 2,2))
      when LINE_7B_DISTURBANCE_HISTORY is null    
        then null
      else null end as YEAR_LOGGED

      from WHSE_FOREST_VEGETATION.VEG_COMP_LYR_R1_POLY vri, WHSE_LAND_USE_PLANNING.RMP_LANDSCAPE_UNIT_SVW lu
      where ORG_UNIT_CODE IN ('DSE')
      and lu.LANDSCAPE_UNIT_NAME = 'Ladybird' 
      and vri.LINE_7B_DISTURBANCE_HISTORY LIKE 'L%'  

      and (
      (SDO_RELATE(vri.GEOMETRY, lu.GEOMETRY, 'mask=OVERLAPBDYINTERSECT') = 'TRUE')
      or (SDO_RELATE(vri.GEOMETRY, lu.GEOMETRY, 'mask=inside') = 'TRUE')  )  )


select table2.vri_OP, table2.GEOM_vri
from table1 right join table2 on table1.forcov_OP = table2.vri_OP
where table1.forcov_OP is null
```

I think the **with** clause may be causing a problem, but it's difficult to know; when I test this in the OSGeo4W window using an ogr2ogr command line, it just gives up, without throwing any error message.

Comment: What is the error? Does `with` cause problems if you use it with  much simpler query?

Comment: You say this is a problem with ogr2ogr yet all you show is a SQL statement. Can you show the failing ogr2ogr command line ?

Comment: Also what exact versions are we talking about ? Database version ? GDAL version ?

Comment: @alphabetasoup : I have scaled back to a simpler query using `with`, and it still fails.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind : I'm using GDAL 2.4.0, and an Oracle 12c database.          

The ogr2ogr command I've assembled is this:      
```E:\sw_nt\QGIS_3.8\bin\ogr2ogr.exe -a_srs epsg:3005 -f "GPKG" T:\_VRI\VRI_simple.gpkg OCI:user/password@IDWPROD1:no_Table -progress -sql @T:\tempQueryFolder\query0.sql -overwrite -nln VRI_simple The SQL is contained in the file referenced by -sql @T:\tempQueryFolder\query0.sql```

Comment: You still did not say in what way it fails. But I just tried that, and what I see is that I do not get any output (the output file is not created). I assume you get the same behavior, i.e. no error, just no output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like ogr2ogr **does not** like SQL statements with a `WITH` clause. The trace shows that it prepares the statement, but then no output is produced. See this example.

Here is the query I run:

```
with s as (
  select state_abrv
  from us_states
  where state = 'California'
)
select c.*
from us_cities c, s
where c.state_abrv = s.state_abrv
```

Running ogr2ogr:

```
$ ogr2ogr   us_cities_select.shp   OCI:scott/tiger@spatialdb:us_cities   -sql @q2.sql

GDAL: Auto register /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/md/gdal/lib/gdalplugins/gdal_GEOR.so using GDALRegister_GEOR.
GDAL: Auto register /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/md/gdal/lib/gdalplugins/gdal_JP2OpenJPEG.so using GDALRegister_JP2OpenJPEG.
GDAL: Auto register /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/md/gdal/lib/gdalplugins/ogr_OCI.so using RegisterOGROCI.
GNM: GNMRegisterAllInternal
GNM: RegisterGNMFile
GNM: RegisterGNMdatabase
OCI: From 'Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production' :
OCI: Version:19
OCI: Release:0
OCI: Prepare(ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY/MM/DD'         NLS_TIME_FORMAT='HH24:MI:SS' NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT='HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM'         NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'         NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT='YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM'         NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '. ')
OCI: Prepare(SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_DEFAULT
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE DATA_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL AND TABLE_NAME = UPPER(:table_name))
OCI: Prepare(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA u, TABLE(u.diminfo) t
WHERE u.table_name = :table_name
  AND u.column_name = :geometry_name)
OCI: get dim based of existing data or index failed.
OCI: Prepare(select m.SDO_LAYER_GTYPE from user_sdo_index_metadata m, user_sdo_index_info i where i.index_name = m.sdo_index_name and i.table_name = upper(:table_name))
OCI: Prepare(SELECT SRID FROM ALL_SDO_GEOM_METADATA WHERE TABLE_NAME = UPPER(:table_name) AND COLUMN_NAME = UPPER(:geometry_name))
OCI: Prepare(SELECT WKTEXT, AUTH_SRID, AUTH_NAME FROM MDSYS.CS_SRS WHERE SRID = 8307 AND WKTEXT IS NOT NULL)
GDAL: GDALOpen(OCI:scott/tiger@spatialdb:us_cities, this=0xef5220) succeeds as OCI.
GDAL: Using ESRI Shapefile driver
GDAL: QuietDelete(us_cities_select.shp) invoking Delete()
GDAL: GDALDriver::Create(ESRI Shapefile,us_cities_select.shp,0,0,0,Unknown,(nil))
OCI: ExecuteSQL(with s as (   select state_abrv   from us_states   where state = 'California' ) select c.* from us_cities c, s where c.state_abrv = s.state_abrv )
OCI: Prepare(with s as (   select state_abrv   from us_states   where state = 'California' ) select c.* from us_cities c, s where c.state_abrv = s.state_abrv )
GDAL: GDALClose(OCI:scott/tiger@spatialdb:us_cities, this=0xef5220)
GDAL: GDALClose(us_cities_select.shp, this=0x10aa110)
```

Contrast with another syntax:

```
select * 
from us_cities 
where state_abrv in (
  select state_abrv from us_states where state ='California'
)
```

The trace shows that the query fully executes and output is produced:

```
$ ogr2ogr   us_cities_select.shp   OCI:scott/tiger@spatialdb:us_cities   -sql @q1.sql
GDAL: Auto register /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/md/gdal/lib/gdalplugins/gdal_GEOR.so using GDALRegister_GEOR.
GDAL: Auto register /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/md/gdal/lib/gdalplugins/gdal_JP2OpenJPEG.so using GDALRegister_JP2OpenJPEG.
GDAL: Auto register /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/md/gdal/lib/gdalplugins/ogr_OCI.so using RegisterOGROCI.
GNM: GNMRegisterAllInternal
GNM: RegisterGNMFile
GNM: RegisterGNMdatabase
OCI: From 'Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production' :
OCI: Version:19
OCI: Release:0
OCI: Prepare(ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY/MM/DD'         NLS_TIME_FORMAT='HH24:MI:SS' NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT='HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM'         NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'         NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT='YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM'         NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '. ')
OCI: Prepare(SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_DEFAULT
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE DATA_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL AND TABLE_NAME = UPPER(:table_name))
OCI: Prepare(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA u, TABLE(u.diminfo) t
WHERE u.table_name = :table_name
  AND u.column_name = :geometry_name)
OCI: get dim based of existing data or index failed.
OCI: Prepare(select m.SDO_LAYER_GTYPE from user_sdo_index_metadata m, user_sdo_index_info i where i.index_name = m.sdo_index_name and i.table_name = upper(:table_name))
OCI: Prepare(SELECT SRID FROM ALL_SDO_GEOM_METADATA WHERE TABLE_NAME = UPPER(:table_name) AND COLUMN_NAME = UPPER(:geometry_name))
OCI: Prepare(SELECT WKTEXT, AUTH_SRID, AUTH_NAME FROM MDSYS.CS_SRS WHERE SRID = 8307 AND WKTEXT IS NOT NULL)
GDAL: GDALOpen(OCI:scott/tiger@spatialdb:us_cities, this=0xed0250) succeeds as OCI.
GDAL: Using ESRI Shapefile driver
GDAL: GDALDriver::Create(ESRI Shapefile,us_cities_select.shp,0,0,0,Unknown,(nil))
OCI: ExecuteSQL(select *  from us_cities  where state_abrv in (   select state_abrv from us_states where state ='California' ) )
OCI: Prepare(select *  from us_cities  where state_abrv in (   select state_abrv from us_states where state ='California' ) )
Shape: DBF Codepage = LDID/87 for us_cities_select.shp
Shape: Treating as encoding 'ISO-8859-1'.
OCI: Prepare(select *  from us_cities  where state_abrv in (   select state_abrv from us_states where state ='California' ) )
GDALVectorTranslate: 44 features written in layer 'us_cities_select'
OCI: 44 features read on layer 'select *  from us_cities  where state_abrv in (   select state_abrv from us_states where state ='California' ) '.
GDAL: GDALClose(OCI:scott/tiger@spatialdb:us_cities, this=0xed0250)
GDAL: GDALClose(us_cities_select.shp, this=0x1085190)
```

The solution seems to encapsulate your query as a view:

```
SQL> create view us_cities_select as
with s as (
  select state_abrv
  from us_states
  where state = 'California'
)
select c.*
from us_cities c, s
where c.state_abrv = s.state_abrv;

View created.
```

Then:

```
$ ogr2ogr   us_cities_select.shp   OCI:scott/tiger@spatialdb:us_cities_select
GDAL: Auto register /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/md/gdal/lib/gdalplugins/gdal_GEOR.so using GDALRegister_GEOR.
GDAL: Auto register /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/md/gdal/lib/gdalplugins/gdal_JP2OpenJPEG.so using GDALRegister_JP2OpenJPEG.
GDAL: Auto register /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/md/gdal/lib/gdalplugins/ogr_OCI.so using RegisterOGROCI.
GNM: GNMRegisterAllInternal
GNM: RegisterGNMFile
GNM: RegisterGNMdatabase
OCI: From 'Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production' :
OCI: Version:19
OCI: Release:0
OCI: Prepare(ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY/MM/DD'         NLS_TIME_FORMAT='HH24:MI:SS' NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT='HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM'         NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'         NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT='YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM'         NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '. ')
ERROR 1: ORA-04043: object us_cities_select does not exist
 in OCIDescribeAny
OCI: Prepare(SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_DEFAULT
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE DATA_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL AND TABLE_NAME = UPPER(:table_name))
OCI: Prepare(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA u, TABLE(u.diminfo) t
WHERE u.table_name = :table_name
  AND u.column_name = :geometry_name)
OCI: get dim based of existing data or index failed.
OCI: Prepare(select m.SDO_LAYER_GTYPE from user_sdo_index_metadata m, user_sdo_index_info i where i.index_name = m.sdo_index_name and i.table_name = upper(:table_name))
OCI: Prepare(SELECT SRID FROM ALL_SDO_GEOM_METADATA WHERE TABLE_NAME = UPPER(:table_name) AND COLUMN_NAME = UPPER(:geometry_name))
GDAL: GDALOpen(OCI:scott/tiger@spatialdb:us_cities_select, this=0xee6140) succeeds as OCI.
GDAL: Using ESRI Shapefile driver
GDAL: QuietDelete(us_cities_select.shp) invoking Delete()
GDAL: GDALDriver::Create(ESRI Shapefile,us_cities_select.shp,0,0,0,Unknown,(nil))
Shape: DBF Codepage = LDID/87 for us_cities_select.shp
Shape: Treating as encoding 'ISO-8859-1'.
OCI: Prepare(SELECT "LOCATION","ID","CITY","STATE_ABRV","POP90","RANK90" FROM us_cities_select )
OCI: Query complete, got 44 hits, and 0 discards.
GDALVectorTranslate: 44 features written in layer 'us_cities_select'
OCI: 44 features read on layer 'us_cities_select'.
GDAL: GDALClose(OCI:scott/tiger@spatialdb:us_cities_select, this=0xee6140)
GDAL: GDALClose(us_cities_select.shp, this=0xfedb80)
```